# Как изменить код чтобы высота сцены была более большой?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

На данный момент, частицы расположены в определенную высоту.
Как поменять код, чтобы высота по сути сцены (этих частиц) зависела от высоту body(то есть в данном случае это 2000px), и чтобы частицы не менялись в размере
https://codepen.io/digikrash/pen/wvpdYmw

```js
var element = document.getElementById("canvas") || document.body;
var options = {};

if (element instanceof HTMLCanvasElement) {
    options.canvas = element;
}

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(options, { antialias: true });

if (!options.canvas) {
    element.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    var canvas = renderer.domElement;
} else {
    canvas = element;
}

// Scene
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

// Camera
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 500;

// Fog
scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0x222125, 0.005, 560, 1000 );

// Variables
var particles, particle, particleMaterial, particleCount, points, texture;
var xSpeed, ySpeed;

// Speed
xSpeed = 0.0005;
ySpeed = 0.001;

// Particles
particleCount = 15000;
particles = new THREE.Geometry();

for (var i = 0; i < particleCount; i++) {
  var px = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
  var py = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
  var pz = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;

  particle = new THREE.Vector3(px, py, pz);
  particle.velocity = new THREE.Vector3(0, Math.random(), 0);
  particles.vertices.push(particle);
}

/* ------------------------------------
// Texture
var sprite = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "textures/sprites/disc.png" );

// Particles material
particleMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
  size: 6.5,
  sizeAttenuation: false,
  map: sprite,
  alphaTest: 0.5,
  transparent: true,
  opacity: 0.8,
  color: 0x45f4d9,
    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending
});
*///-----------------------------------
var material = new THREE.PointsMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } ) // Only for Codepen
//-------------------------------------

// Points
points = new THREE.Points(particles, material);
points.sortParticles = true;
scene.add(points);

// lights
var light1, light2, hemiLight;

light1 = new THREE.PointLight( 0x52ffef, 100, 600);
light1.position.set( -200, 300, 300 );
light1.castShadow = true;
light1.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048;
light1.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048;
scene.add( light1 );

light2 = new THREE.PointLight( 0x53ffd1, 50, 600);
light2.position.set( 250, -300, 300 );
light2.castShadow = true;
light2.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048;
light2.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048;
scene.add( light2 );

hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 5 );
hemiLight.color.setHSL( 0.6, 1, 0.6 );
hemiLight.groundColor.setHSL( 0.095, 1, 0.75 );
hemiLight.position.set( 0, 500, 0 );
scene.add( hemiLight );

// Resize
var resize = function() {
    var width = canvas.clientWidth;
    var height = canvas.clientHeight;
    if ( canvas.width != width || canvas.height != height ) {
        renderer.setSize( canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight, false );

        camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }
};

// Render
var render = function() {
  // Call resize
  resize();

  // Animate particles randomly
  var i = particleCount;
  while(i--){
    var particle = particles.vertices[i];

    // Animate y
    if(particle.y > 1000){
      particle.y = -1000;
      particle.velocity.y = Math.random();
    }

    particle.velocity.y += Math.random() * ySpeed;
    particle.add(particle.velocity);
  }

  points.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

  // Points to go upwards
  points.rotation.y += xSpeed;

  // Call scene and camera
  renderer.render( scene, camera );

  // Update animation frame
  requestAnimationFrame( render, canvas );
};

// Call render
render();
```

```css
canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1500px;
}
body {
    height: 2000px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/84/three.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

так? не совсем понял вопрос

```
canvas {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 10000px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: как мне увеличить саму сцену чтобы она была во весь body, наврятли дело в css, надо менять js

Comment: я просто хочу эти частицы на задний фон поставить у body

Comment: Чем position fixed не устраивает? В данном варианте частицы будут на все body, неважно боди 100px или 10000px, такой вариант и адаптировать под мобилку проще, чем через скрипт

Comment: когда я буду скролить вниз, просто на заднем фоне будут эти частицы фиксированными, это очень некрасиво, лучше тогда уш, их полностью убрать

Comment: [Частицы на весь body](https://codepen.io/eugene-kul/pen/ExovgOx)
[Фиксированные частицы](https://codepen.io/eugene-kul/pen/jOYLMQe)

Специально оставил оранжевый цвет, чтобы было видно, как canvas "ездит" за скроллом.
Во втором варианте, при скроле частицы плавают, это не красиво

Comment: но к сожалению, мне нужны фиксированные